# Hidden div with html string and move content to span and then encode string to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small problem with the content I'm hiding in my hidden `td` element

```
<td class="hidden">
    <span class="taxDescription hidden">@Html.Raw(@benefit.TaxDescription)</span> 
</td>
```

and I want to move it into this `span` but I don't want to lose my html encoding of the string using JS or JQuery.

```
<div class="spanDiv">
    <span class="taxDescription">@Html.Raw(((Model.EmployerBenefits.Any()) ? Model.EmployerBenefits[0].TaxDescription : ""))</span>
</div>
```

The code I have for this right now is as follows:

```
$(".benefitsList .benefitListItem").click(function () {
    var taxDescription = $(this).find("span.taxDescription").text();
    $("div.top span.taxDescription").html(taxDescription);
});
```

but the thing is that I lose my TinyMCE formatting of the string and just gets plain text
I think the problem is just under my giant nose and I just can't seem to find it.

If this is to little information please point it out and ask for more an I'll try to provide you with it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it will help - you were grabbing `text` and then inserting it as `html`.

```
$(".benefitsList .benefitListItem").click(function () {
    var taxDescription = $(this).find("span.taxDescription").html();
    $("div.top span.taxDescription").html(taxDescription);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it was right there the whole time i tried .html() on the first but not on the second :) if i could i would 1+